# Google Chrome Bookmark Folders - Can you Undo 'Reorder By Title'?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, undo

In my Google Chrome v53, I have hundreds of bookmarks groped into around 20 folders. Folders were arranged as they were created over a period of time.  Certain links that I access frequency were always on the visible part of the bookmarks bar and others grouped into various folders.

Unfortunately while in bookmarks manager, I accidentally clicked ‘Reorder by Title’ and now all my top level folders and links are sorted alphabetically and folders occupy visible part of the bookmarks bar pushing those frequently accessed links to bottom of the list which can be accessed by clicking the Right Arrow at the extreme right corner .

Is there any way to undo this operation and restore the original order the way it was?

There’s no Undo available within Chrome’s options though, for this particular action.

Thanks.

Comment: My previous answer was incorrect. 'Reorder by Title' permanently changes the position of bookmarks. However, they still have their date saved, so you can export, switch the position of DOM elements by some script, and import your bookmarks back. I'm working on a quicker solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found one. [Recent Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn) extension can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I shall try this extension and let you know.

Comment: Not too sure how this extension works but it seems to be listing all bookmarks without the directories in some order. However I have manually moved the bookmarks to their original places to the best of my memory!

Answer (score 0):

Try click again the 'Sort by name' so that the undo button appear again. Click on the undo to see whether your original order come back. Mine works.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the main Google Support threads: The first one is still open for reply, and another user suggested the extension below. It doesnt restore the order, but has a separate manager that can sort by date. It can filter by folder too.

How do you change your bookmarks back to sorted by date instead of by name?
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2178394?hl=en

How do i revert alphabetically sorted tabs to chronological order?
https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0guL0GB5u1yc

Starmarks Bookmark Manager
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/starmarks-bookmark-manage/ohhpijmpbgndokpodomgiclmflhbkihb?hl=en

Bookmarks Table (better readability)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-table/eaabmhkokgaboihbikohlooneokghmcp

Its possible to export the bookmarks to HTML file for importing into a different profile or Chrome app, maybe Chromium. As the extensions here show, the date information is still there, but when looking at the HTML file, the entries are ordered by name. The file imports this way unfortunately. A script could reorder the HTML file by 'ADD_DATE="1524340449"'. It would need to for loop through each `<DT><H3` folder, recursively and sort each `<DT><A HREF=` entry by that ADD_DATE.

EDIT: I was just reminded that I created a similar question not too long ago on SO. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695456/sort-chrome-bookmarks-by-date-newest-first

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you add an A, B, C,D, ect. to the ones you want at the front and add X,Y,Z ect. at the ones you want at the end. Sort by name (again) then delete the extra letters. Its pretty easy, but takes work if you have a lot of bookmarks.